# Swift custom segue doesn't work on consecutive segues

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I made a custom segue that moves the current view to the left and moves the next view in from the right at the same time. When I used it on the first  segueway it works perfectly, but when used in the next segueway only the destination view moves. The code for the segue looks like the following:

```
class CustomSlideSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        let firstVCView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
        let secondVCView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

        let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
        let screenHeight = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

        secondVCView.frame = CGRectMake(screenWidth, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)

        let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: { () -> Void in
             firstVCView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-screenWidth, 0)
             secondVCView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-screenWidth, 0)
    }) { (Finished) -> Void in
            self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController as UIViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code from the view controller button action method where I start the segue:

```
performSegueWithIdentifier("customSlideSegue", sender: self)
```

Here is a video showing the segues:

[image: The second slide happens after the image picker.]

Can anyone see the problem? Or how should I go about debugging this? Thankful for replies!

Comment: can you show some more code where you actually use the custom segue?

Comment: Added it to the question. I use the performSegueWithIdentifier("customSlideSegue", sender: self) in the method thats called then the button is pressed.

Comment: I of course have different IDs on both the segues :)

Comment: can you maybe share your project to take a look?

Comment: https://github.com/jacobarvidsson/Noodle-Doodle

Comment: haha. i like the name... :) will take a look...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the second time you call the segue the sourceviewcontroller's view's transform already has a value of `-screenWidth` and thus it doesn't get pushed out of the screen. change your code to the following:

```
override func perform() {
    let firstVCView = self.sourceViewController.view as UIView!
    let secondVCView = self.destinationViewController.view as UIView!

    let screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width

    secondVCView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(screenWidth, 0)

    let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
    window?.insertSubview(secondVCView, aboveSubview: firstVCView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: { () -> Void in
        firstVCView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-screenWidth, 0)
        secondVCView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }) { (Finished) -> Void in
        self.sourceViewController.presentViewController(self.destinationViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought it would reset the transform when I reset the frame! I'm very new to animations and custom segues in iOS, I appreciate the time you took to help me!